# Setting a thread priority in a service has no effect

Tags: multithreading, winapi, process, windows-services, thread-priority

Is there some additional configuration needed before I can set thread priorities in a Windows service?

In my service, I have a few threads that each call the `CreateProcess()` function to launch an external application. I would like to adjust thread (or process) priorities to `normal` or `lower`, depending on some other factors.

The problem is that `SetThreadPriority()` function fails with an error 6 (invalid handle?). I'm passing in a handle obtained from `PROCESS_INFORMATION::hThread` (after calling the `CreateProcess()` of course), so I think that the handle *should* be valid.

I've also tried setting the priority on the processes using the `SetPriorityClass()` function, which also fails.

The service is logged on as a local user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you don't have the correct access rights? [MSDN on SetThreadPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686277(VS.85).aspx) says:

> hThread [in] A handle to the thread
>   whose priority value is to be set.
>
> The handle must have the
>   THREAD_SET_INFORMATION or
>   THREAD_SET_LIMITED_INFORMATION access
>   right. For more information, see
>   Thread Security and Access Rights.
>
> Windows Server 2003 and Windows
>   XP/2000:  The handle must have the
>   THREAD_SET_INFORMATION access right.

Comment: It's possible. I'm trying to pass in a SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR to the CreateProcess() in hopes that I can get full access, but it doesn't appear to have any effect, as I'm still getting an error 6 and priorities are not changed. I may be doing something wrong in setting this though.