# Make Executable run at a lower priority

Tags: c#, windows-services, service

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting a thread priority in a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239160/setting-a-thread-priority-in-a-service)

I've created a Windows Service and I want it to always run at LOW priority.   Is there any way to achieve this via code or how I package up the install?

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239160/setting-a-thread-priority-in-a-service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239160/setting-a-thread-priority-in-a-service).

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the value of the Thread.Priority property?

Comment: I'd be curious to know of the results if you get this working.

Comment: The solution was to change the PriorityClass of the process.  CurrentThread.Priority did not work.  I wish there was a way to use Startup Params on the service or a reg setting, but there was not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try modifying `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass` and/or `System.Threading.CurrentThread.Priority`.

Note that: "threads with different priorities that are running in the process run relative to the priority class of the process" (1).  Also, changing the `Priority` property of a `ThreadPool` thread has no effect.

1) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.priorityclass.aspx

2) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.priority.aspx